# What is the purpose of nesting a unit test inside the class it tests, rather than in another (outside) class?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I've been looking through [a particular open source library](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/blob/master/hystrix-core/src/main/java/com/netflix/hystrix/HystrixCommand.java#L1830) in which all unit tests are defined as static nested class inside the class they test, for example:

```
public class Foo {

    public int bar() { ... }

    public static class UnitTest {
        @Test
        public void testBar() { ... }
    }
}
```

I've never seen a project or Java codebase that does this before and I am really curious about the thinking behind it.

- Is there any advantage over this pattern than having a separate `FooTest` class in another source folder `src/test/java`?
- Is this a convention of projects that use [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org) as their build tool?

Comment: If you're asking why *one specific project* does something you've never seen anywhere else, it suggests it might be better asked on that project's mailing list.

Comment: Only reason I can think of is that putting the test inside the class gives the test easy access to non-public variables and methods.

Comment: @JonSkeet true, but I was also curious if maybe this was a pattern in use outside of my small corner of Java-world

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Jon Skeet suggested, I found the answer [within the documentation of the project](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/FAQ) in question:

> Hystrix has all of its unit tests as inner classes rather than in a separate /test/ folder.

> Why?

> - Low Friction

- Context
- Encapsulation
- Refactoring
- Self-documenting

> More information on the reasoning can be found in this blog post: [JUnit Tests as Inner Classes](https://web.archive.org/web/20141224170143/http://benjchristensen.com/2011/10/23/junit-tests-as-inner-classes/)

Answer (score 3):

There doesn't seem to be any advantage writing unit tests as a nested inner class besides access to private members.  The disadvantages that I can think of are:

- It makes your Java classes pretty honking big and unwieldy.
- The final jar file will have testing code in it which is probably unnecessary during production runtime and is generally not a good practice (keeping production code separate from test code).

Also, according to the Gradle docs for the [Java plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html), it recommends keeping tests in src/test/java so I don't think that this is a Gradle-specific convention at all.